# Key press delay settings in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I remember I used to be able to set how long before the OS repeat the key that I press (delay before first repeat), and how fast the OS repeat the key that I press (delay between repeats).

I can't find this settings in Windows 10 version 1809. Didn't find them by typing 'keyboard' in start menu. They are not available in Settings - Devices - Typing.

Is these settings still available? Where can I find them?

Comment: Start > Run > "control" > Keyboard,  (change View By to Icons)

Comment: @DavidPostill ah the old control panel. Got it!